# Angular NPM Run Prod: Error npm ERR! missing script: prod

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular10

I am running npm with a new Angular Project and receiving error below. How can fix this?

```
npm ERR! missing script: prod
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\..2020-11-19T05_27_19_941Z-debug.log
```

[image: Error preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means you don't have a configuration for `prod` in your scripts. Basically to run any angular project you need to make sure the scripts or commands are defined inside your `package.json`. Most angular projects will have a script configuration like below

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

So, you can run either `ng serve` or `npm start` in your command to start the application.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have the script : `prod` in your package.json file. If you want to run the angular project, you can use `ng serve` or `npm run start`